# Regex to split a string on number of characters but to get whole words

Tags: regex

I'm currently using a regular expression to split a string into substrings of 15 characters:

```
(?<=\G.{15})
```

Example text:
First second third fourth fifth sixthsixthsixthsixthsixthsixth seventh

splits into:

```
[0] => First second th
[1] => ird fourth fifth
[2] =>  sixthsixthsixth
[3] => sixthsixthsixths
[4] => ixth seventh
```

I would like to modify this a bit to:
Split into 15 characters or less, but only split on whitespace in order to get whole words.
If there is a word from the split in #1 that is longer than 15 characters then split that.

This could get messy though. If I have a word that is longer than 15 characters I want that word to be split, and then the following substring should 15 characters also, not just the second half of the word.

For the above example, I would like:

```
[0] => First second 
[1] => third fourth 
[2] => fifth
[3] => sixthsixthsixth
[4] => sixthsixthsixth 
[5] => sixth seventh
```

I would also be happy with:

```
[0] => First second 
[1] => third fourth 
[2] => fifth sixthsixt
[3] => hsixthsixthsixt
[4] => hsixthsixth 
[5] => seventh
```

If the first two cannot be done in a single regex then I might be happy with:

```
[0] => First second 
[1] => third fourth 
[2] => fifth
[3] => sixthsixthsixth
[4] => sixthsixthsixth 
[5] => sixth 
[6] => seventh
```

the difference between the two is that I split the long string in a different spot.

Is it possible to do this with a single regex?

Comment: and what is your language?

Comment: What is `\G`? Never seen that shorthand class before o_O

Comment: Precisely `\G` means [beginning of string or end of previous match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: I'm using this regex in Java and Ruby. I was hoping the question would be language-agnostic.

Comment: I know the word boundary \b should be used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing the language makes it much more clear to know which tokens and constructs should be used. If you are using Ruby v2.0 or greater you are fine with this one:

```
(.{1,15}\b|.{15})\K(?: +|\B|\Z)
```

By replacing match with a newline `\n` you will get a string split in the way you want:

```
First second
third fourth
fifth
sixthsixthsixth
sixthsixthsixth
sixth seventh
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE1hB8/2)

If you need them as an array of captured groups only, then there is a shorter way:

```
(.{1,15}\b|.{15})
```

[Live demo](http://rubular.com/r/QZ9prb5148)

Explanation:

```
  (           # Begin capturing group (1)
    .{1,15}   #   Match 15 characters max (greedy)
    \b        #   Till reaching a word boundary
    |         #   Or
    .{15}     #   Match those parts of a long word
  )           # End of (1)

  \K          # Reset whatever is matched so far

  (?:         # Begin non-capturing group
     +        #   Match white-spaces
    |         #   Or
    \B        #   A non-word boudanry
    |         #   Or
    \Z        #   End of string
  )           # End of non-capturing group
```

Comment: Thanks - both of those examples work for me. One strange thing - I get very slightly different results with this regex example engine: https://myregextester.com/index.php

but I think I can just try these in my code and see what I get. Even the slightly different results are better than what I had before.

Comment: First one uses `\K` token which is not supported by Java and second one can almost be used in all regex flavors. @RobertA.Decker

Comment: I made a slight change when I found out that \b splits on characters that are used in urls, for example. It's now:
(.{1,15}(?:\s|$)|.{15})

15 characters obviously isn't what I'm really using - I just kept it short for the demo purpose.